# Move @AnalyzerDef Analyzer definition into a separated class

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm following the documentation at [THIS](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_searching) link and I would like to move the Analyzer definition into a separated class.

This is the code block I would like to move, in order not to have it binded to a specific entity.

`@Entity
 @Indexed
 @AnalyzerDef(name = "customanalyzer",
  tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
  filters = {
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
      @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English")
    })
  })
public class Book {
   @Field
   @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
   private String title;
....`

Basically I would like to have all this definied into a separated class, and add only `@Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")` into my entity class.

Any ideas? Thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your only option would be to move the definitions to a `package-info.java` file and fill it with this content:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "customanalyzer",
  tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
  filters = {
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
      @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English")
  })
})
package org.whatever.my.package.is;
```

Note that you must have at least one annotated entity in this package, otherwise Hibernate Search will just ignore it.

---

Hibernate Search 5.8 will offer an experimental, dedicated programmatic API allowing to define analyzers in a global fashion, but this feature hasn't been released yet (not even in the latest 5.8.Beta2).

Answer (score 0):

The design of `@AnalyzerDef` in Hibernate Search is really poor. You cannot for example extract a separate library with analyzers definitions and use them amongst your services or applications. They require to introduce indexable entity if you want to define analyzer definition.

However, you can create a fake entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select * from analyzers_definition")
@Indexed(index = "analyzers_definition")
@AnalyzerDef(...)
public class AnalyzersDefinition {
  @Id protected Long id;
}
```

Because of `@Subselect` annotation the table won't be created in the db, but `@AnalyzerDef` annotations will be consumed properly. The only drawback is that "analyzers_definition" index will be created in your Lucene/ElasticSearch/whatever storage. But that's looks a little problem.